# Why is my lib forcing the inclusion of mfc40.lib?

Tags: c++, mfc, linker

So I was beating my head against my desk for days trying to figure out why my MFC project kept  failing at link phase because it couldn't find mfc40.lib. I checked for `#pragma comment`, I checked for lib inputs in project settings, i grepped folder after folder, I could find NOTHING.

Just before I was about to lose my mind, I realized that grepWin ignores LIB files for some reason, so I opened up an old lib in my text editor and saw this:

> -defaultlib:mfc40.lib -defaultlib:mfcs40.lib -defaultlib:msvcrt.lib -defaultlib:kernel32.lib -defaultlib:user32.lib -defaultlib:gdi32.lib -defaultlib:comdlg32.lib -defaultlib:winspool.lib -defaultlib:advapi32.lib -defaultlib:shell32.lib -defaultlib:comctl32.lib /include:_*afxForceEXCLUDE /include:*_afxForceUSRDLL /include:__afxForceSTDAFX -defaultlib:LIBC
>   -defaultlib:OLDNAMES

For some odd reason the above human-readable portion was actually in the LIB file itself, so I can only assume that because I link against this lib directly, it is INDIRECTLY forcing the inclusion of mfc40.lib (and friends).

Is this what is happening? Why is the above inside the LIB file? An explanation of why this happens would be a bonus.

Also the lib in question is from the Exchange SDK. I'm compiling this MFC project in VS2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If when you created the project for your library you chose an MFC based library, whichever version of MFC is available gets added as a default library. To remove it, in your project properties go to Linker > Input > Ignore Specific Libraries and enter mfc40.lib.

More info on that property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz4da4a%28v=VS.90%29.aspx